# Does specifying many/every variations of "apple-touch-startup-image" and "apple-touch-icon" eat up the applicationCache's filesize limit?

Tags: ios, icons, filesize, iphone-standalone-web-app, application-cache

When designing web apps to run offline, should one be concerned about the #s of files and filesize for each of the startup images / homescreen icons so that it doesn't go beyond the applicationCache's filesize limit? *Note: I think it is 5MB (correct me if I'm wrong).*

Consider this long exhaustive list of icons and startup images:
https://gist.github.com/tfausak/2222823